# Select SQL Query for two table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables

**Table A :** Content Question , its options and correct answer

**Table B :** This table is for time allow to answer the question in given time.
this table has Question_Id field which either have question id  or zero. zero means if for Table A Question Id is not found in Table B then default Time will be Table B's Question_Id=0 > 5 Min

Now I want the data like Result table from query. By using Select Query with Join I am getting question details, which are matched with question Id (1,2,4)  means for Question 3,5,6 row not getting that showing in result table.

[image]

Please suggest what sql query should write so that I can get result like Result Table's content.

Comment: I'm sorry this doesn't your answer question but Table B looks redundant. Why not just add the timing statement to table A?

Comment: With rep > 1000 you should know that you need to show what you've tried. Also, your data is inconsistent.  There are no rows in B for Question IDs 3, 5 and 6 so the Result Table is impossible given the other two.

Answer (score 1):

I change your tables to small and simple tables and you can see the result in:

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ae46/2)

or try this query:

```
SELECT t1.questionid, 
       t1.question, 
       t1.options, 
       t1.answer, 
       COALESCE(t2.timingstatement, '5 Min') TimingStatement 
FROM   tablea t1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tableb t2 
                    ON t1.questionid = t2.questionid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Q.QuestionID,Q.Question,Q.Options,QAnswer,
       CASE WHEN Q.QuestionID NOT IN (SELECT QuestionID FROM Table2) THEN '5 Min'
            ELSE T.TimingStatement
       END [TimingStatement]
FROM Table1 Q
JOIN Table2 T ON Q.QuestionID = T.QuestionID
```

Comment: When we applying Q.QuestionID=T.QuestionID, It will not list 3,4,6

Comment: you can use Outer Join right??